# SQL query can't get the code right in C# and I don´t know what is wrong

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have four tables in my database.

- Car Table(tbl_Auto)
- Vehicle type (tbl_Fahrzeugtyp)
- Car Brand (tbl_Marke)
- Car Model (tbl_Modell)

And a C# program with 3 combo boxes. From first combo box I chose Vehicle Type, from 2nd Car Brand, and From the 3rd Car Model.

It should work like this:

1. If I chose Vehicle Type (Coupe) from the first combo box,
2. in the second should appear only brands that have such vehicle type in my database (for an example BMW), and then
3. in the third should appear Models of BMWs that are Coupe vehicle type (for an example M5).

When I use SQL in my database query works so I´m guessing there something wrong with my C# code. From the code below, the first function works, i get all the vehicle types into combo box, but the second one doesn't. And if i run the query in SQL server it works, so i think the problem is it doesn't read the first combo box correctly. The problem is I get the blank second combo box.

```
public partial class Mieten : Window
{
    public Mieten()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fill_comboFtyp();
        fill_comboMarke();
    }

    public void fill_comboFtyp()
    {
            string connString = "Data Source= DADDO_PC\\SQL2012;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog= ITIBB_G1_C";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            conn.Open();

            string anfrage = "Select FTypBeschreibung From tbl_Fahrzeugtyp";
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(anfrage, conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string fTyp = dr.GetString(0);
                fahrzeugtyp.Items.Add(fTyp);
            }

            conn.Close();
        }

        public void fill_comboMarke()
        {
            string connString = "Data Source= DADDO_PC\\SQL2012;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog= ITIBB_G1_C";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            conn.Open();

            string anfrage = "Select Markenname From tbl_Marke join tbl_Auto on tbl_Marke.Marken_ID =tbl_Auto.Marken_ID join tbl_Fahrzeugtyp on tbl_Fahrzeugtyp.Fahrzeugtyp_ID=tbl_Auto.Fahrzeugtyp_ID where tbl_Fahrzeugtyp.FTypBeschreibung='"+fahrzeugtyp.Text+"'";
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(anfrage, conn);

            SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string markenname = dr.GetString(0);
                marke.Items.Add(markenname);
            }

            conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have `FirstComboBox_OnSelectedIndexChanged()` to run a SQL query that looks for all the brands that have `vehicle_type = FirstComboBox.Value`.

Comment: Thanks you were right. I have one more question. Now it works but if i make a selection from combo boxes for an example i chose caravan from first box and there are 2 Brands that have caravan. if i change it to coupe it adds the brand that have coupe but the caravan vehicles are there as well. I have to restart it every time if i want to change the selection

Comment: Yes, basically before running the query for the 2nd combo box you are meant to clear all the brands that were already inside, use    ComboxBox.Item.Clear() at the top of     FirstComboBox_OnSelectedIndexChanged()